# Embedding assembly in C with compiler finding registers for you

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

When embedding assembly code into a C/C++ program, you can avoid clobbering registers by saving them with a push instruction (or specify clobber list of compiler supports it).

If you are including assembly inline and want to avoid the overhead of pushing and popping clobbered registers, is there a way of letting gcc choose registers for you (e.g. ones it knows have no useful info in them).

Comment: please add the 'homework' tag, also please note that this is not meant to be a homework-only site, so you'll have to provide what you've got so far, for other people to chime in and provide the rest.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is a theoretical question so there is no 'code' so far.

Comment: Why are you assuming this is homework?  I never had homework ask me details about using gcc.. This is very much an issue that is faced once you actually try to achieve something in the real world.

Comment: ok, my bad sounded pretty much like HW - so I'm very sorry, but gcc is regularly used for CS classes, so that type of question wouldn't really surprise me at all.

Comment: You should add the gcc flag, since the answer for gcc (or any other compiler for which there is an answer) is *very* compiler specific.  The C and C++ standards are very demure on "asm".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  You can specify that you want a particular variable (input or output) to be stored in a register, but you don't have to specify a register.  See [this document](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for a detailed explanation.  Essentially, the inline assembly looks like this:

```
asm("your assembly instructions"
      : output1("=a"),  // I want output1 in the eax register
        output2("=r"),  // output2 can be in any general-purpose register
        output3("=q"),  // output3 can be in eax, ebx, ecx, or edx
        output4("=A")   // output4 can be in eax or edx
      : /* inputs */
      : /* clobbered registers */
   );
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually skimmed that file before posting but missed it. Now having taken a long time just to read those small sections I can see why! It's not pretty, but it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Compiler intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx?ppud=4) are a very useful way to mix assembly and C/C++ code. They're declarations that look like functions, but actually compile directly to individual native instructions (via a special case inside the compiler). This gives you much of the control of working in assembly, but leaves the register coloring and scheduling up to the compiler.

An advantage is that then you can pass an ordinary C variable into an intrinsic, and let the compiler take care of loading it onto the register and scheduling other ops around it. For example,

```
struct TwoVectors
{
   __m128 a; __m128b;
}

// adds two vectors A += B using the native SSE opcode
inline void SimdADD( TwoVectors *v ) 
{
   v->a = _mm_add_ps( v->a , v->b ); // compiles directly to ADDSS opcode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I can't leave a comment above, but I'm pretty sure that the correct syntax (different from that shown above) is:

```
asm ( "your assembly instructions"
    : "=a"(output1),
      "=r"(output2),
      "=q"(output3),
      "=A"(output4)
    : /* inputs */
    : /* clobbered registers */
);
```

Although you can leave the allocation of input and output registers to the compiler, there's no obvious way of leaving the allocation of scratch/temp registers (i.e. used for intermediate values but not an input or output) to the compiler. Historically, I just listed them explicitly in the clobber list (e.g. "%xmm1", "%rcx"), but I now think it might be better to list them as outputs in order to allow the compiler to choose them. I don't know of any source that addresses this issue definitively.